# Debugging a segmentation fault when calling a third party executable

Tags: c++, gdb, segmentation-fault

On Rhel5, I am getting a segmentation fault while calling a third party C++ executable.

Unfortunately, I do not have the ability to re-compile this third party executable with the DEBUG flags enabled. So for that reason, the core dump from the segmentation fault unfortunately doesn't provide us with much information, neither Both gdb and valgrind.

For example, here is valgrind:

```
==4074== Process terminating with default action of signal 11 (SIGSEGV)                                                                                                              
==4074==  Access not within mapped region at address 0x7158E7F7                                                                                                                      
==4074==    at 0x7158E7F7: ???                                                                                                    
==4074==    by 0x6322203A22656D6E: ???                                                                                                                                               
==4074==    by 0x306C675F6E557267: ???                                                                                                                                               
==4074==    by 0x202C22373232302F: ???                                                                                                                                               
==4074==    by 0x6D616E656C696621: ???                                                                                                                                               
==4074==    by 0x72686322203A2264: ???                                                                                                                                               
==4074==    by 0x3030306C675F6E54: ???                                                                                                                                               
==4074==    by 0x346469702E373231: ???                                                                                                                                               
==4074==    by 0x646469662E34372F: ???                                                                                                                                               
==4074==    by 0x722E64616568656B: ???                                                                                                                                               
==4074==    by 0x63656D6F6C756764: ???
```

Is there any way, maybe through lsof or something, to get information to the third party vender on what caused the issue?

Comment: First of all, I believe vendor should tell what information it needs. Usually there should be some kind of a crash report, memory dump along with system configuration information. I don't see a point in debugging what you cannot fix yourself anyway.

Comment: That's a good point. The product is Adobe Live Cycle, within it contains a c++ binary that it calls from the main java program. that's where this seg fault is coming from.

Comment: That stacktrace looks like it is full of text, if I had to guess I would say you wrote over the bounds of an char array, by many many bytes. Try printing the current stack contents as hexdump/ascii. The stirngs seem to look like: c" :"emn0lg_nUrg ,"7220/manelif!rhc" :"d000lg_nT4dip.721ddif.47/r.daehekcemolugd

Comment: Actually I don't know any reliable way in debugging segfaults without knowing program internals.. Even with that they are hell of challenge to debug sometimes.

Comment: Why are you trying to debug a third party's executable for them? Get them to fix it!

Comment: Like PlasmaHH says, it looks like the stack is full of text - which is usually a sign of a buffer overflow. But it would be almost impossible to debug without at the very least knowing what the code is doing - something for the vendor to deal with. If you can reproduce it reliably, then providing a small, simple test case of "doing this causes it to go wrong" - this often involves stripping down input to something that is small and short, etc.

Comment: The product is actually adobe live cycle. it delegates work to a XMLForm EXE service. When this is called, it segmentation faults and then I cannot figure out why. Adobe hasn't provided any debug information yet. any other tricks techniques using strace? If i can find the library causing it, chances are - i can change the library path to avoid the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We found the answer using strace

In particular

```
strace -f -o strace.txt $myPath/bin/XMLForm $* ${MISSING_LOCALE} ORBtraceLevel 40 -ORBtraceThreadId 1
```

This generated a strace.txt file that contained all the low-level C-API calls.

And wouldn't you know it, right before the segmentation fault.... the program was looking for a log file that didn't exist. we added that log, bam no more seg fault.